# Require JS base path for variable URL structures

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having difficultly using RequireJS on any of the subsidiary pages on my project build. The base URL is appended to the page URL and so causes 404 errors... Here is the JS:

```js
require.config({
    "baseUrl": "content/themes/my-theme",
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
        "foundation": "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "foundation": ["jquery"]
    }
});

require(['jquery', "foundation"], function($) {

    $(document).foundation();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('Working!!');
    });
});
```

Fair simple... So **when I run this on my the root domain of my website (e.g. `http://my-domain.com/`), everything works fine** and I get the console log of `Working!!` as expected. The included resources, for example jQuery, is called in to the correct URL:

```
http://my-domain.com/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

**The problem is that when I visit an internal page, the `baseURL` is appended to the page URL and so it then points incorrectly, causing the file request to 404.** Here's some examples of the URL's:

```
http://my-domain.com/about-us/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 
http://my-domain.com/category/uncategorized/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

As you can see the page URL extension `/about-us/` or `/category/uncategorized/` is the problem.

I've looked through the documentation and must be missing the solution to the problem. Please can you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baseUrl` can be left empty and a sensible default will be set.

You can set the `baseUrl` to the URL of your site such as `baseUrl : "http://my-domain.com/content/themes/my-theme/"`

Perhaps a contributing issue is that the paths do not start with a slash (see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths)

In conclusion, you can try the following:

```
require.config({
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
        "foundation": "/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "foundation": ["jquery"]
    }
});

require(['jquery', "foundation"], function($) {

    $(document).foundation();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('Working!!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. The full solution for me was to remove the `baseURL` reference and include the full path for each for each of the dependencies e.g: `"foundation": "/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min"`